# Close textinput for a textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, winapi, textbox

Is there a way I can, in C#, close the text input popup that is visible when you tap a `TextBox`?

I thought of setting focus to the LayoutRoot or ContentPanel (both parent grids) in my app but that does not work.

Comment: Do you mean hiding the keyboard?

Comment: @Alaa Masoud I want to hide the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

focusing the current page will hide the keyboard for you.

Make an extension method to get current active page

```cs
 public static PhoneApplicationPage GetActivePage(this Application application) {
     PhoneApplicationPage content = null;
     if (application != null) {
         PhoneApplicationFrame rootVisual = application.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
         if (rootVisual != null) {
             content = rootVisual.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
         }
     }
     return content;
 }
```

Then you can do this:

```cs
Application.Current.GetActivePage().Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you an alternative, for example you can do something like:

```
 private void YourTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            YourTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
            YourTextBox.IsEnabled = true;  
        }
```